# Can't get underscore.js to use curly braces without syntax error

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Anyone know why this doesn't work? I'm trying to get _.template to use  braces.

```
    _.templateSettings = { //change delimiter to <$ $>
          interpolate : /\<\$(.+?)\$\>/g
        };      
    var list = "<$ _.each(people, function(name) { $> <li><$ name $> </li> <$ }); $>";
    var html=_.template(list);
    console.log(html({people : ['moe', 'curly', 'larry']}));
```

It produces the following syntax error error at )):

> ((__t=( *.each(people, function(name) { ))==null?'':*_t)+

Here's what the Underscore documentation says:

> If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change
>   Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off
>   interpolated code. Define an interpolate regex to match expressions
>   that should be interpolated verbatim, an escape regex to match
>   expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an
>   evaluate regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without
>   insertion into the resulting string. You may define or omit any
>   combination of the three. For example, to perform Mustache.js style
>   templating:
>
> _.templateSettings = {   interpolate : /{{(.+?)}}/g };
>
> var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!"); template({name :
>   "Mustache"});
>   => "Hello Mustache!"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that something interpolated should produce a stand-alone JavaScript expression and this:

```
_.each(people, function(name) {
```

is not a valid expression. You need to define separate *evaluate* and *interpolate* regexes and then use the *evaluate* one for the `_.each`; something like this:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
};
var list = "{{_.each(people, function(name) {}} <li>{{=name}}</li> {{ }); }}";
```

Note that interpolation now uses `{{= ... }}` and `{{ ... }}` is just for evaluating (or embedding) little JavaScript snippets.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SDmLz/